# How to create an interruptible loop in node.js

Tags: node.js, events, asynchronous

Disclaimer: I'm a Node.js newbie and the following description may be lengthy...

I'm currently trying to teach myself Node.js for a little project I'm after. The project idea is the following: a RaspberryPI runs a Node.js application which allows me to control the colors of an RGB LED strip. The application should be able to set both a static color and also run color wheels that smoothly change colors.

My idea is now to create several Node.js scripts:

1. A "controller" that does the client communication, sets static colors or is able to start a color wheel
2. "client scripts" that each run a color wheel. At most one of them would be "alive", started/stopped by the "controller"

I've been able to create a little script that forks another script and is able to stop that script using `child.send` as follows:

**controller.js**

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork,
    test2 = fork(__dirname + '/test2.js');

setTimeout(function() { test2.send({func: 'quit'}); }, 5000);
```

This forks the `test2.js` script and after 5 seconds sends a `quit` message that quits `test2.js`.

**test2.js**

```
function runLoop()
{
  console.log("Hello");
  setTimeout(runLoop, 1000);
}

process.on('message', function(m) {
  if (m.func === 'quit')
  {
    process.exit(0);
  }
});

setTimeout(runLoop, 1000);
```

This "client script" prints "Hello" every second until the controller sends the `quit` message.

This works pretty well - after 5 seconds the scripts finish gracefully.

My question is now: If I implement a color wheel, I'll need a possibly endless loop that changes the colors of the LED strip. Would the above (with shorter timer values of course - I need something like 10ms here) be a feasible way of implementing an interruptible loop or is there some neater mechanism I don't know of yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making the life complicated. Your global architecture is as follows:

```
external trigger --> listener ----------> code that changes color
(ie. web client)     (ie. web server)
```

With that in mind you don't need to fork any process, you can control the LED strip within a single process. Somewhere in your code you'll have an object similar to this:

```
//"led" is the module that allows you to change the color of a led (suppose 4 leds)
var led = require ("led-controller");

var ColorChanger = module.exports = function (){
    this._intervalId = null;
};

ColorChanger.prototype.setColor = function (hex){
    //Color in hexadecimal

    //Cancel any current interval
    cancelInterval (this._intervalId);

    led.color (0, hex);
    led.color (1, hex);
    led.color (2, hex);
    led.color (3, hex);
};

ColorChanger.prototype.wheel = function (hex, ms){
    //Color in hexadecimal
    //"ms" is the time interval between leds going on and off

    //Cancel any current interval
    cancelInterval (this._intervalId);

    //Shutdown all the leds
    led.off (0);
    led.off (1);
    led.off (2);
    led.off (3);

    //Activate the first led
    led.color (0, hex);

    //Current active led
    var curr = 0;

    this._intervalId = setInterval (function (){
        //Each "ms" the current led will go off and the next will go on
        led.off (curr);
        //Next led to activate
        curr = ++curr%4;
        led.color (curr, hex);
    }, ms);
};
```

Then the listener module uses the `ColorChanger`.

```
var ColorChanger = require ("./color-changer");

var changer = new ColorChanger ();

//Set all the leds to red
changer.setColor ("#FF0000");

//Each 10ms one led goes green and the previous is turned off, in an endless loop
changer.wheel ("#00FF00", 10);
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me this quite elegant way of doing things. :-) I understand what you're doing here and this solution seems to me like a very elegant way of implementing also different color wheel types within the `ColorChanger` class.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `setTimeout`, you shouldn't even need to fork a new process.  Here's how I would write your example:

```
var ntrvl = setInterval(function() { console.log('Hello'); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(ntrvl); }, 5000);
```

... very simple.  With `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, you're using asynchronous functions, so you will not block the event loop.  When the timer is up, it runs your code, then waits for the next event.  You should be able to control all of your "clients", you'll have bandwidth for far more than you'll actually need, all in the same process in this way, concurrently.

All you need to be wary of is that you're not blocking the script.  If you attempt to perform any action synchronously (which means that the script will wait for the action to complete before performing the next command), then you need to make sure it runs quickly.  If you have to run processor/time intensive tasks synchronously, that's when you'll need to fork a new process.

Comment: Thank you for this answer - I understand that while forking may be "over the top" here, I *could* do it to make sure a smooth color wheel is not interrupted by what the controller is doing (and to keep things modular, which I also want to do)?

Comment: As long as everything is properly asynchronous then the single threaded performance would be indistinguishable from what you're doing here, and has the "side benefit" of being the way node is meant to work. I don't know what module or library you're using to actually interact with the lights, so if it's not asynchronous then what you're doing would be necessary.